# crash on Andorid programming when using Volly to make Json request

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I get this crash error report when i'm push the application button to make array request:

```
01-31 16:55:51.713 3745-3745/com.example.guidofabbrini.easyracevolley E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: com.example.guidofabbrini.easyracevolley, PID: 3745
                                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.guidofabbrini.easyracevolley.AppController.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                at com.example.guidofabbrini.easyracevolley.MainActivity.makeJsonArrayRequest(MainActivity.java:120)
                                                                                                at com.example.guidofabbrini.easyracevolley.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:21)
                                                                                                at com.example.guidofabbrini.easyracevolley.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // json array response url
    private String urlJsonArry ="http://pastebin.com/raw/puYnpK96";
    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnMakeArrayRequest;

    // Progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private TextView txtResponse;

    // temporary string to show the parsed response
    private String jsonResponse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnMakeArrayRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnArrayRequest);
        txtResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        btnMakeArrayRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // making json array request
                makeJsonArrayRequest();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Method to make json array request where response starts with [
     * */
    private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

        showpDialog();

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {
                            // Parsing json array response
                            // loop through each json object
                            jsonResponse = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) response
                                        .get(i);

                                String position = data.getString("position");
                                JSONObject pilot = data
                                        .getJSONObject("pilot");
                                String name = pilot.getString("name");
                                String lapcount = data.getString("lap_count");
                                String avglaptime = data.getString("avg_lap_time");

                                jsonResponse += "Position: " + position + "\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Pilot: " + name + "\n";
                                jsonResponse += "LapCount: " + lapcount + "\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Avg_LapTime: " + avglaptime + "\n\n";

                            }

                            txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }

    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

My Application

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the code in `AppController.class`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing a single line in your AndroidManifest.xml under the application tag:

```
<application
    android:name="YourPackage.AppController"
```

this line is indicating the fully qualified name of the Application subclass that you implemented.